# Problems in for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio

Though this problem seems trivial I`m unable to proceed further in R ( I could do this quite easily in Python)

I hv a folder which has 300 0dd CSV files I`m supposed to find the number of complete cases in each of them .

```
file_names <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)      
first <- NULL    

for(i in length(file_names)) {     
    first <- complete.cases(read.csv(file_names[i]))        
    sum(first)    
 }
```

The output which I expected was for each i I would get a sum(first) I hv nor been able to get anywhere close to that . Why is that a simple for loop in R is causing such issues. Any kind of help would b appreciated

Comment: It's unclear what your desired output is here. Were you assuming the values would print to the screen? Inside a loop values aren't displayed without an explicit `print()` call.

Comment: You don't need the "first <- NULL" line, by the way; that's not going to do anything useful (it's a loosely-typed language, and a NULL is a very different type from a data.frame)

Comment: @MrFlick No....I seemed 2 hv missed d print() call here.

Comment: @OliverKeyes Ok... Thnkx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put a `1:` in front of length, that argument needs to be a vector of values that `i` takes. The way you wrote it it only takes the one value.

```
for(i in 1:length(file_names)) {     
    first <- complete.cases(read.csv(file_names[i]))        
    sum(first)    
 }
```

also, don't print the output, assign it to something.

```
output=rep(NA,length(file_names))
for(i in 1:length(file_names)) {     
    first <- complete.cases(read.csv(file_names[i]))        
    output[i]=sum(first)    
 }
```

Comment: I answered by fixing your code, tim's answer below is a more R literate solution.

Answer (score 0):

alternative with sapply

```
sum(sapply(file_names, function(fn) { sum(complete.cases(read.csv(fn))) }))
```